# How to preserve & re-submit request while doing an OAuth2 token refresh?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, google-api, oauth-2.0, google-oauth

I'm writing a Google calendar app in rails.  The OAuth2 access token expires after 1 hr.  My problem is, if someone fills out a form that I want to push to Google calendar, and while they are filling out the form the access token expires and they have to go thru the whole re-authentication process, I don't know how to preserve the entire request (form submission) and resubmit it, once my token is refreshed.

I know it's possible using a DB, saving the params, the path, the request method, and all that... but what I want to do is save everything in a session variable of some sort, and have it automatically re-submit the whole request to my app again, once the Google OAuth access token is valid.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

This is solvable by getting a `refresh_token` with which you can get a new `access_token`. You can do that by asking for [offline access](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2WebServer#offline) when the user first authorizes your app.

You can also use the [Ruby client library](https://code.google.com/p/google-api-ruby-client/wiki/OAuth2) that Google provides to manage the OAuth2 process easier for you.

Answer (score 0):

You can also save the form state in the current session, assuming you have one, then do an immediate flow just to grab a new access token. See the prompt=none parameter:
https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2Login#authenticationuriparameters

The immediate flow will succeed only if the user has a valid session with Google. If that's not the case then you do have to send the user to re-authenticate in the normal flow.

Or, as Arun suggested, use a refresh token. But with a refresh token you definitely have to run you own session and keep a user database (you have to store the refresh token). Your own session may also expire before the form is submitted.